# How to obtain real VPN connection status (it claims to be connected in airplane mode / without internet)?

Tags: privacy, internet, vpn, airplane-mode

My Google Pixel 5 claims to have a VPN connection, although I enabled the airplane mode. How can I ever be sure that the VPN connection is really working then if I have an internet connection?

I would expect "not connected" and not "this device is connected with ...":

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The VPN status only reflects whether any app has created a TUN device via [VpnService.Builder API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.Builder.html) (i.e. all or selected traffic is routed to that app), not whether the VPN connection established by that app is actually working/connected.

Comment: This does not answer my question. Or isn't there a way to check the connection itself?

Comment: Only the VPN app itself would have that information (no guarantee that it actually does, it may still think it's connected). And it only has limited ways to publish that (e.g. via notification or maybe a custom Quick Settings tile).